# Media projection permission dialog popup again & again in (Samsung Android 14 One UI 6) && Pixel 6 (Android14)

Tags: android, android-mediaprojection, android-14, mediaprojection, mediaprojectionmanager

Device :  (Samsung Android 14 One UI 6)  && Pixel 6 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lRRB.png)
Issue: the media projection permission dialog is shown again & again in the above-mentioned device.
but it was working fine with other devices. I have no idea how to solve this issue.

I have used this code.Pls check

```
private fun setupMediaIntent() {
        try {
            if (!screenshotUtil.isMediaProjectionEnabled()) {
                val mediaProjectionManager =
                    context?.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE) as MediaProjectionManager

                startForResult.launch(mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent())
            } else {
                handleNavigation()
            }
        } catch (exx: Exception) {
            exx.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

```
private val startForResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { activityResult ->
            try {
                if (activityResult.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    screenshotUtil.setResultCode(activityResult.resultCode)
                    screenshotUtil.setMediaProjectionIntent(activityResult.data)

                    ServiceUtils.restartService(
                        requireContext(),
                        ServiceType.AUTO_SCREENSHOTS.value
                    )
                    handleNavigation()
                } else {
                    setupMediaIntent()
                }
            } catch (exx: Exception) {
                exx.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

private fun handleNavigation() {
        PreferencesUtils.setPreference(requireContext(), SETUP_FINISHED, "true")
        PreferencesUtils.setRestartVirtualDisplay(requireContext(), "false")
        if (initialSetup || fromDashboard) {
            LogUtil.writeLog(
                requireContext(),
                "Initial Permission",
                "Media Projection Permission Enabled"
            )
            findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.mainFragment, false)
        } else {
            activity?.finishAffinity()
        }
        Constants.finishes = true
    }
```

Excepting Behavior : the permission dialog should not popup again & again one it enabled

Answer (score 1):

Don't release MediaProjection, VirtualDisplay, ImageReader, repeat Use mImageReader.acquireLatestImage().

Comment: can you pls explain it  bro in detail

Answer (score 0):

if "isMediaProjectionEnabled()" returns TRUE you have to provide same "activityResult.data" as before, or the Dialog will be shown. It's a strange behaviour but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you don't shut down the surface at any point on android 14+ before you are completely done with media projection, had that issue myself. Couldn't find why my service didn't work, then discovered I had shut down the surface immediately after capturing a valid frame. By leaving the surface, image reader, and virtual display active, you'll be able to just use something like this repeatedly. Beware that this approach is constantly consuming resources as well!

```
 val image = imageReader.acquireNextImage()
        if (image != null) {
            val planes = image.planes
            val buffer = planes[0].buffer
            val pixelStride = planes[0].pixelStride
            val rowStride = planes[0].rowStride
            val rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * width
            val bitmapWidth = width + rowPadding / pixelStride
            if (latestBitmap == null || latestBitmap!!.width != bitmapWidth || latestBitmap!!.height != height) {
                latestBitmap?.recycle()
                latestBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapWidth, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            }
            latestBitmap?.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer)
            image.close()
```

Comment: stilll we facing issues bro

Comment: Did you get it figured out? I got a reliable method working rn, took a while though. Willing to share if you still need help

Comment: Please share the method; let's see whether it works or not @Droid Automations

Comment: @KirubakaranM sorry 4 the late reply, haven't been on her for a while, [here's a link](https://github.com/android-automations/android14ScreenshotActivity) to the base code I'm using, some methods, classes, such as the code to obtain the mediaProjection permission isn't here, this isn't a drag and drop replacement 4 whatever code you have. Hopefully it helps you though, and would love feedback if you have suggestions, etc! Built my code largely off of [this project](https://github.com/cvzi/ScreenshotTile)

Comment: will definitely try  and let you know @Droid Automations thanks a lot